# xcode function menu keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos, xcode3.2

I'm somewhat new to XCode and am very accustomed to using Visual Assist with Visual Studio.  In XCode, I see the function menu above the text editor but can't seem to find a keyboard shortcut to pop it down.  It seems to require a mouse click.  It would be nice to have as this is yet another tool for better code navigation and is easily accomplished with Visual Assist using Alt-m.

Anyone know the magic incantation for XCode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Control 2
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 12):

Ctrl + 6 opens the function menu for me.
Take a look under View > Editor for some related shortcuts. (*See note below*)

Unsurprisingly, you can start typing the name of the function to select it, instead of using the arrow keys.

I'm using Xcode 4, by the way.

**NOTE**:
The program [CheatSheet](https://www.cheatsheetapp.com/CheatSheet/) lets you see a list of all keyboard shortcuts in the current program by holding down the command key (⌘) for 2 seconds.

Comment: Too bad that app is not available anymore, or not in my country maybe?